# Highlight particular string in SWT Tree node

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a requirement like first of all tree will be loaded, tree contains 4 levels.

There is a text field, where user can enter "filterText" and he can press search button.

In tree, in any of four levels if there is a match with filter text, then that particular string only should be highlighted with yellow color but not whole node and its corresponding tree will be expanded.

Unmatched tree nodes should not expand.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using `TreeViewer`.

You can use a `StyledCellLabelProvider` to set different styles for parts of the label string. The `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` class is derived from this class to make things a bit easier. Set up the label provider using:

```
viewer.setLabelProvider(new DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider(myLabelProvider));
```

where `myLabelProvider` is a class implementing `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.IStyledLabelProvider`. The provider has a `getImage` method as usual plus:

```
public StyledString getStyledText(Object element)
```

which uses a `StyledString` which allows you to apply different styles to the text. Something like:

```
StyledString text = new StyledString();

text.append("unstyled text");

text.append("styled text with decorations style", StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
```

as well as the predefined `StyledString.Styler` values you can define your own. The `DefaultStyler` class lets you use colors defined in the JFace color registry.

A simple version of a styler to set the background to yellow would be:

```
class HighlightStyler extends Styler
{
  @Override
  public void applyStyles(final TextStyle textStyle)
  {
    textStyle.background = Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi greg, its not solving my problem...
With help of Graphic Conext(GC) can we acheive it?

Comment: It is definitely possible with this but you will have to create your own Styler, show your code. To use a GC you would have to use `OwnerDrawLabelProvider`.

Comment: I noticed I mistakenly used StyledText - should be StyledString