# Java SWT TreeViewer with one column that needs to be StyledText

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, treeviewer, styledtext

I have a `TreeViewer` used in an eclipse plugin that uses a content provider and a label provider that implements all of (`ITableLabelProvider`, `IFontProvider`, `IColorProvider`).

But I need one of the columns of the table it creates to hold "links"  - underlined blue text that when clicked causes some popup to open. I guess what I want to do is cause that single column to hold styled text and not just text, and attach a listener to the items in that column of the tree, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can use `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` as a column label provider similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26173834/2670892

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Greg. But I didn't understand how to apply the styled text only to a single TreeColumn (the index is known, obviously). Oren

Comment: Added a answer with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a separate label provider for each column using `TreeViewerColumn`:

```
TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(.....);

TreeViewerColumn col1 = new TreeViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEAD);

col1.setLabelProvider(col1 label provider);

... repeat for other columns
```

For columns that require styling use `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` as the column label provider as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173834/highlight-particular-string-in-swt-tree-node)

Note: Do not call `viewer.setLabelProvider` when using column label providers.

Comment: I don't have a TableViewer, I have a TreeViewer. Is this still applicable?

Comment: Sorry not reading carefully enough. Updated answer to TreeViewerColumn

Comment: Sorry for being a pain... I tried that and eclipse forced me to have the new label provider extend CellLabelProvider in addition to implementing the interface (or I cannot use setLabelProvider). But it doesn't seem to call the getStyledText on the cells, and if I don't use it for all columns I just get their object representation. What am I missing?

Comment: Use `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` for columns that require styling, `ColumnLabelProvider` for those that do not. Both extend `CellLabelProvider`.

Comment: OK, I got this to work - almost. For some reason the StyledText.fontStyle doesn't "catch" - my instructions for bold/italic are ignored. Other than that all is honey sweet. Any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about `StyleRange.fontStyle`? This code only supports `TextRange`. You would have to set `TextRange.font` to change the font.