# Using a DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider with an ITableLabelProvider

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, tableviewer

I am trying to style specific cells in my table that have a specific attribute. I have used a DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider in the past for a Tree structure, and was hoping to do the same here.

However, I can't figure out how to get it working with my ITableLabelProvider.

I saw questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211705/java-swt-treeviewer-with-one-column-that-needs-to-be-styledtext) that suggested using IColumnLabelProviders instead of the ITableLabelProvider, but I really don't want to go back and change my code.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` will not work with the old style `ITableLabelProvider` as it does not support multiple columns. You must use separate column label providers.

Comment: the ITableLabelProvider is considered "old style"? I was under the impression that it is better practice to use it.

Comment: Yes, it predates the separate column support.